# I have to call multiple different web services in parallel using C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, parallel.for, parallel.invoke

I have a requirement where I need to send multiple parallel calls to different web services hosted on different servers. I have to read a configuration file to know how many times the call has to be made. Let say there are 4 servers and on each server a web service is hosted. The configured value is 4 then I have to make 4 calls to each service in parallel. Total calls would be 16. Here is the code which I have done:

```
string XmlFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLFile"].ToString();
            int num = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberOfCalls"]);

Service service1 = new InfoMsg.Manager.Service();
Service service2 = new InfoMsg.Manager.Service();
Service service3 = new InfoMsg.Manager.Service();
Service service4 = new InfoMsg.Manager.Service();

string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(XmlFile);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString))
{
    Parallel.For(0, num, i =>
        Parallel.Invoke(() => service1.CheckInXML(xmlString), 
                        () => service2.CheckInXML(xmlString), 
                        () => service3.CheckInXML(xmlString), 
                        () => service4.CheckInXML(xmlString))
    );
}
```

I am actually making between 14 and 16 calls so something is wrong. Is it a correct way to do this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Did it work?

Comment: Yes! its working. But I am not sure if I am doing it in a correct way

Comment: Sometimes calls are less than what I expect. Let say value of num is 4 then total calls should be 16

Comment: So what are you *actually* getting, when you expect 16, and how are you measuring what you're actually getting?

Comment: sometimes 14, sometimes 16. I am checking the service calls in fiddler.

Comment: I think it is enough if you remove the Parallel.Invoke. The Parallel.For should do the work.

Comment: How I will make all 4 service calls in Parallel.For? I have to call these 4 service calls in parallel.

Comment: Yes! it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @AshwiniKumar: I post is as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question it is enough if you remove the Parallel.Invoke. The Parallel.For should do the work, that's what the Parallel.For essentially does.